# torsion-free sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have a stupid question. Let $X$ be a singular curve over a field. Let $F$ be a torsion-free sheaf generically (outside singularities) of rank one. 
Is $F$ coherent?

Comment: Can someone translate this problem into Commutative Algebra language? (i.e., in terms of rings, localization, modules,...)

Comment: @YACP: this is possible if $F$ is supposed to be quasi-coherent. In this case, the question is: let $A$ be a domain (finitely generated over a field and of Krull dimension one), let $M$ be a torsion-free $A$-module, free of rank one over some localization $A_f$. Is $M$ finitely generated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the open regular locus $U\subset X$ and assume the curve is affine and integral. Then extending $\mathcal O_U$ by zero in $X$ yields an $\mathcal O_X$ module that is coherent on $U$ but not even quasicoherent on $X$. See Hartshorne eg II.5.2.3.